# How to use regex in find

Tags: regex, find

I'm trying to use regular expression in find.
Here is my command:

```
for GLOBALS_DEFINITIONS in `find . -type f -name -regex 'globalSettings_\d+.json'`; do
```

In result:

```
find: paths must precede expression:
```

Comment: Drop the `-name`.

Comment: Still not works.

Comment: The regex must match the whole path, not just the filename. And the syntax is that of Emacs regexp, unless you change it with `-regextype`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is caused by the `-name` parameter. You should use either `-name` or `-regex` but not both together:

```
find . -type f -regex 'globalSettings_\d+.json'
```

However, note that the regular expression must match the *full path* not just the filename. So, let's say you want to match only files in the current directory, you would do:

```
find . -type f -regex './globalSettings_\d+.json'
```

If deeper matches are okay (which is normally the reason to use `find` in the first place), you could do:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/globalSettings_\d+.json'
```

Regarding the `\d` part, however, note that by default, `find` uses Emacs' regexp syntax where `\d` does not match digits. You could do this instead:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*/globalSettings_[0-9]+.json'
```